# error correction for the PHP code

Tags: php, jquery

I have written the following code and not able to figure out the errors in it..

It not poping out any errors ..what it does is that it just stays on the html page

whats wrong in it?

html page

```
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
 function get(){
$("#button1").click(function(){
$.post('script_1.php', { name: form.name.value },
function(output) {
$('#age').html(output).show();
}) ;
});
 } 

$("#button2").click(function(){
$('form#myForm').attr({action: "script_2.php"});
$('form#myForm').submit();
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="myForm" method="post">
doi: <input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="button" id="button1" value ="Get" onclick="get();"/>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Submit to script 2" />
title:<input type="text" name="title"/>
</form>
<div id="age"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

script_1.php for the first button is

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
//connect to database

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);



 if ($name==NULL)
 echo "please enter an id!";
 else
 {   
 $age= mysql_query("SELECT title FROM parentid WHERE id ='$name'");
 $age_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($age);   
  if ($age_num_rows==0)
  echo "id does not exist";

else
{

$sql ="SELECT * FROM parentid WHERE id = '$name'";       
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$abc_output= "Existing data of the record <br />";      
$abc_output .="Title: " . $row['title'] . "<br />" ;
$abc_output .="Report No: " .  $row['reportno'] . "<br />" ;
$abc_output .="URL: " .  $row['calc_url'] . "<br />" ; 
$abc_output .="Institution: " .  $row['institution'] . "<br />" ; 

}
}
echo $abc_output;

}
}
?>
```

script_2.php is another php file

with update operation in database.

//title form is only used in script_2.php for updation.
script_1.php is used for displaying already present elements in DB.

Help appreciated.

Comment: For your queries, is id a numeric value or a string value?

Comment: That is your problem, then.  You are using $name which is the name of someone.  You need to find the $id of the person and use that instead of their name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight problem with your HTML and Javascript code.  The way you declared the click functions, was improper.  Try this:

```
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $.post('script_1.php', { name: $('input[name$="name"]', '#myForm').val() },
            function(output) {
                $('#age').html(output).show();
            });
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $('form#myForm').attr({action: "script_2.php"});
        $('form#myForm').submit();
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="myForm" method="post">
doi: <input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="button" id="button1" value ="Get"/>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Submit to script 2" />
title:<input type="text" name="title"/>
</form>
<div id="age"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are your two SQL queries that you asked for:

```
$age= mysql_query("SELECT title FROM parentid WHERE id =(select id from parentid where name='$name')");


$sql ="SELECT * FROM parentid WHERE id = (select id from parentid where name='$name')";
```

Comment: what is the difference here?? for the ) you removed..we need to close both function and $.post..

Comment: The difference between this and what you have is that you had illegal function declarations for your click events which were preventing the click functions from ever firing.  I have tested this bit of code that I have posted and it does submit the information.

Comment: Hey it took me some time to realize what u said..my first button is not submitting anything ..what it is doing is just getting information from the database(no submission)..

Comment: I edited my answer to include the two queries now.  I don't know where you keep your name varialbe.  My guess was parentid.

Answer (score 0):

a few things pop into mind, first, where you have this:

```
 if ($name==NULL)
 echo "please enter an id!";
```

it should be more like

```
 if (empty($name))
 echo "please enter an id!";
```

next, you have this:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

and it should me more like

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
else echo "they didnt use the form.";
```

and finally, i do not see and code to actually connect to a database.

Comment: as for your con posting issue, why do you need 2 submit buttons in the first place?

Comment: one submit button is for bringing the information present in the DB(it gives the info present in the DB the info will be displayed on the same html page) and another submit is for updating the data in the DB..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i have a solution for you.

here is my example form

```
<form action='posted.php' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='b1' value='Button 1' /><br />
<input type='submit' name='b2' value='Button 2' /><br />
</form>
```

and here is 'posted.php'

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['b1'])) echo 'Button 1';
if(isset($_POST['b2'])) echo 'Button 2';
?>
```

when you press 'Button 1', the php gives 'Button 1', and the same goes for button 2.